# How to simplify by Factorization

Tags: matlab, expression, simplify

How to simplify an expression like below:

input   :    `a*b*c+a*d*e+b*d*f+c*e*f`

output  :    `a*(b*c+d*e)+f*(b*d+c*e)`

I try collect and factor in MATLAB but It's not my favorite output

collect output :   `(b*d + c*e)*f + a*b*c + a*d*e`

factor output  :   `a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with `collect`.  However, if you look at the [`collect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html) documentation, you can only factor **one** variable at a time.  If you want to achieve factoring two variables at a time, you have to call `collect` twice - once for each variable you want to factor.  You would need to specify an additional input into `collect` that tells the function which variable you want to factor with.  By using `collect` by itself with no parameters other than your symbolic expression, it factors on the default variable that is determined [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) which would be `f` in your case.  As such, if you want to achieve what your post says, you would need to do this:

```
syms a b c d e f; %// Define symbolic variables 
eqn = a*b*c+a*d*e+b*d*f+c*e*f; %// Define expression
final_eqn = collect(collect(eqn, f), a)

final_eqn = 

(b*c + d*e)*a + (b*d + c*e)*f
```

---

## Something to think about...

MATLAB has a utility called [`simple`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simple.html) where it tries various simplification functions on your expression, and outputs what each of those simplifications are.  If you try this on your expression, this is what you get:

```
>> simple(eqn);

simplify:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


radsimp:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


simplify(Steps = 100):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


combine(sincos):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


combine(sinhcosh):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


combine(ln):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


factor:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


expand:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


combine:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


rewrite(exp):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


rewrite(sincos):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


rewrite(sinhcosh):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


rewrite(tan):

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


mwcos2sin:

a*b*c + a*d*e + b*d*f + c*e*f


collect(f):

(b*d + c*e)*f + a*b*c + a*d*e
```

I guess it isn't particularly useful in your case, but it's something to take a look at if there is a simplification algorithm you're not happy with.  You can try all of them with `simple` and you can choose the best one that is suitable for you.